# Boost ASIO: notify on all tasks pending

Tags: c++, boost, c++20, boost-asio

Imagine there are 3 tasks registered to an ASIO `io_context` A, B and C. A might be running right now and by the time it's done C is ready to run so it does but even by the time that completes B isn't ready. I'd like to be able to register a handler to be called in the case where no tasks are currently able to make progress. The system I'm building could benefit from essentially being able to say "there is nothing left to do right this second, you have some time for more computationally intensive tasks".

Comment: Have you seen the prioritized handlers example?

Comment: @JeffGarrett there's actually two radically different ones, AFAIR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The system I'm building could benefit from essentially being able to say "there is nothing left to do right this second, you have some time for more computationally intensive tasks".

The way to do that is usually to have dedicated task queues so you can detect when specific loads are high, low or even idle. Basically, unrelated to Asio, which merely has an eventloop with its own queues related to asynchronous operations.

That said, you can frequently use a timer as an event, like

```
asio::steady_timer    t(ex, asio::steady_timer::time_point::max());

// when all tasks done, do
t.expires_at(asio::steady_timer::time_point::min());
```

Also, you can use the new `parallel_group` feature: [Coordinating Parallel Operations](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/composition/parallel_group.html). Keep in mind, this is still geared towards asynchronous operations, of course.

You don't specify what [completion mechanism](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/composition.html) your code uses, but in the case you were thinking if using C++20 stackless coroutines, you can have syntactic sugar with the parallel groups, like:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0539c6b2608a9dc4)**

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/awaitable_operators.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using namespace asio::experimental::awaitable_operators;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using tcp = asio::ip::tcp;

asio::awaitable<void> delay(auto duration) {
    co_await asio::steady_timer( //
        co_await asio::this_coro::executor, duration)
        .async_wait(asio::deferred);
}

asio::awaitable<void> session(tcp::socket s) {
    std::cout << "Accepted " << s.remote_endpoint() << " on " << s.local_endpoint() << std::endl;
    auto upstream   = []() -> asio::awaitable<void> { co_return; /* TODO */ };
    auto downstream = []() -> asio::awaitable<void> { co_return; /* TODO */ };

    co_await (upstream() && downstream());
}

asio::awaitable<void> listener(uint16_t port) {
    auto ex = co_await asio::this_coro::executor;
    tcp::acceptor acc(ex, {{}, port});
    for(;;)
        co_spawn(ex, session(co_await acc.async_accept(asio::deferred)), asio::detached);
}

int main() {
    asio::thread_pool ioc(1);

    asio::signal_set ss(ioc, SIGINT);
    auto interrupted = ss.async_wait(asio::use_awaitable);

    co_spawn(ioc,
             (listener(8989) && listener(8443)) || delay(10s) || std::move(interrupted), //
             asio::detached);

    ioc.join();
}
```

With online output:

```
g++ -std=c++20 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp
./a.out&
(for a in {1..5}; do sleep 0.$RANDOM; netcat 127.0.0.1 8989 -w 0 <<< "HELLO"; done)&
(for a in {1..5}; do sleep 0.$RANDOM; netcat 127.0.0.1 8443 -w 0 <<< "HELLO"; done)&
time wait
Accepted 127.0.0.1:51650 on 127.0.0.1:8443
Accepted 127.0.0.1:51652 on 127.0.0.1:8443
Accepted 127.0.0.1:51654 on 127.0.0.1:8443
Accepted 127.0.0.1:51656 on 127.0.0.1:8443
Accepted 127.0.0.1:46716 on 127.0.0.1:8989
Accepted 127.0.0.1:51660 on 127.0.0.1:8443
Accepted 127.0.0.1:46720 on 127.0.0.1:8989
Accepted 127.0.0.1:46722 on 127.0.0.1:8989
Accepted 127.0.0.1:46726 on 127.0.0.1:8989
Accepted 127.0.0.1:46728 on 127.0.0.1:8989

real    0m10.006s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m0.012s
```

As you can see, even though it is all geared to async operations, you can already achieve some "highlevel" semantics with it.